# read_csv fails on bad lines despite error_bad_lines=False

Tags: python, pandas

I have several csv files that contain 5-10 million rows, a date column and 38 float columns. The first 2 lines look like this:

```
TimeStamp,Delta_TP9,Delta_AF7,Delta_AF8,Delta_TP10,Theta_TP9,Theta_AF7,Theta_AF8,Theta_TP10,Alpha_TP9,Alpha_AF7,Alpha_AF8,Alpha_TP10,Beta_TP9,Beta_AF7,Beta_AF8,Beta_TP10,Gamma_TP9,Gamma_AF7,Gamma_AF8,Gamma_TP10,RAW_TP9,RAW_AF7,RAW_AF8,RAW_TP10,AUX_RIGHT,Accelerometer_X,Accelerometer_Y,Accelerometer_Z,Gyro_X,Gyro_Y,Gyro_Z,HeadBandOn,HSI_TP9,HSI_AF7,HSI_AF8,HSI_TP10,Battery,Elements
2021-08-23 22:28:18.075,0.3433317,-0.13125433,0.19724153,0.3780492,0.29566488,-0.11979784,-0.13724233,0.15123636,0.60538906,0.05333593,0.057029862,0.6922968,0.47216785,-0.10591815,-0.07170116,0.7612045,0.082151726,-0.48873997,-0.46962842,0.5869229,780.4762,801.02563,807.0696,765.56775,925.12823,0.32745361328125,0.3243408203125,0.88421630859375,7.813262939453125,0.538330078125,2.94586181640625,1,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,100.00
```

However, every few thousand lines I see a line like this:

```
2021-08-23 22:28:18.702,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/muse/elements/blink
```

As these files are very large and frequently read, I'd like to provie `pandas.read_csv` with the number types, and simply skip those invalid lines:

```
pandas.read_csv(mypath, dtype='float64', parse_dates=['TimeStamp'], error_bad_lines=False)
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-d03cdaea5d7c> in <module>
----> 1 pandas.read_csv(mypath, dtype='float64', parse_dates=['TimeStamp'], error_bad_lines=False)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    603     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    604 
--> 605     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    606 
    607 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    461 
    462     with parser:
--> 463         return parser.read(nrows)
    464 
    465 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1050     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1051         nrows = validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1052         index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1053 
   1054         if index is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2054     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2055         try:
-> 2056             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2057         except StopIteration:
   2058             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '/muse/elements/blink'
```

I would prefer not to have to modify the csv files, or to parse the csv as object types and remove the erroneous rows later (due to the impact this has on memory usage).

Comment: Also set warn_bad_lines to True.

Comment: @Roxy. `warn_bad_lines` raised a `FutureWarning: The warn_bad_lines argument has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version` (Pandas 1.3.0)

Comment: @Roxy setting `warn_bad_lines=True` seems to have had no effect

Answer (score 1):

You can read the first line of your file to get column names and skip the last column `Element`:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('data.csv') as fp:
    headers = fp.readline().strip().split(',')[:-1]
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, header=None, names=headers,
                     parse_dates=['TimeStamp'], dtype=float)

df.drop(df[df[headers[1:]].isna().all(axis=1)].index, inplace=True)
```

```
>>> df
                TimeStamp  Delta_TP9  Delta_AF7  Delta_AF8  ...  HSI_AF7  HSI_AF8  HSI_TP10  Battery
0 2021-08-23 22:28:18.075   0.343332  -0.131254   0.197242  ...      1.0      1.0       1.0    100.0

[1 rows x 38 columns]
```

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 38 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------           --------------  -----
 0   TimeStamp        1 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   Delta_TP9        1 non-null      float64
 2   Delta_AF7        1 non-null      float64
 3   Delta_AF8        1 non-null      float64
 4   Delta_TP10       1 non-null      float64
 5   Theta_TP9        1 non-null      float64
 6   Theta_AF7        1 non-null      float64
 7   Theta_AF8        1 non-null      float64
 8   Theta_TP10       1 non-null      float64
 9   Alpha_TP9        1 non-null      float64
 10  Alpha_AF7        1 non-null      float64
 11  Alpha_AF8        1 non-null      float64
 12  Alpha_TP10       1 non-null      float64
 13  Beta_TP9         1 non-null      float64
 14  Beta_AF7         1 non-null      float64
 15  Beta_AF8         1 non-null      float64
 16  Beta_TP10        1 non-null      float64
 17  Gamma_TP9        1 non-null      float64
 18  Gamma_AF7        1 non-null      float64
 19  Gamma_AF8        1 non-null      float64
 20  Gamma_TP10       1 non-null      float64
 21  RAW_TP9          1 non-null      float64
 22  RAW_AF7          1 non-null      float64
 23  RAW_AF8          1 non-null      float64
 24  RAW_TP10         1 non-null      float64
 25  AUX_RIGHT        1 non-null      float64
 26  Accelerometer_X  1 non-null      float64
 27  Accelerometer_Y  1 non-null      float64
 28  Accelerometer_Z  1 non-null      float64
 29  Gyro_X           1 non-null      float64
 30  Gyro_Y           1 non-null      float64
 31  Gyro_Z           1 non-null      float64
 32  HeadBandOn       1 non-null      float64
 33  HSI_TP9          1 non-null      float64
 34  HSI_AF7          1 non-null      float64
 35  HSI_AF8          1 non-null      float64
 36  HSI_TP10         1 non-null      float64
 37  Battery          1 non-null      float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(37)
memory usage: 312.0 bytes
```